# How to create a variable in crontab for a date from last week

Tags: crontab

I am trying to set up a cron job, using a script that needs to be occasionally run interactively.

So far it looks like this:

59 1 * * 1 /weekly.csh `date +\%Y\%m\%d` `date +\%Y\%m\%d` >> log

What I really want, is for the first date variable to be todays date, minus seven days (ie. last week) and the second variable to remain as is (today's date).

How can I do this???
Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Why was this downvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> 59 1 * * 1 /weekly.csh date +\%Y\%m\%d --date="-1 week" date +\%Y\%m\%d >> log